# Puzzled by x86 MOV instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, mov, instruction-encoding

From Intel64 & IA-32 manual vol 2a, there are many possible usage for instruction `mov`. Such as:

```
mov r64, m64      # move m64 to r64

mov rax, moffs64  # move quadword at (offset) to RAX
```

I wrote code to test (gas, intel syntax):

```
movabs rax, label

movabs rax, offset label

...
label:
    .quad 0x112233445566
```

After assembly, linking and objdump, I got related assembly:

```
mov rax, qword ptr ds:0xffff80000000008e
mov rax, 0xffff80000000008e
```

Obviously, the second instruction I wrote is not the instruction expected as manual. What's the instruction for the format in the manual?

Comment: The assembler will choose between those two versions automatically, the assembly is the same. Your `movabs rax, offset label` is neither of the two, it's `mov r64, imm64`. If you want to see the first version, that is the `mov r64, m64` then use some other register than `rax`, such as `mov rdx, label`.

Answer (score 2):

`moffs` denotes a memory operand. Here's the description from the Intel manual:

> `moffs8, moffs16, moffs32, moffs64` — A simple memory variable (memory offset) of type byte, word, or
>   doubleword used by some variants of the `MOV` instruction. The actual address is given by a simple offset
>   relative to the segment base. No `ModR/M` byte is used in the instruction. The number shown with `moffs`
>   indicates its size, which is determined by the address-size attribute of the instruction.

The `offset` operator, which is used by assemblers like MASM and TASM, gives you *"the offset into the relevant segment of [the operand]"* [(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/009k3eeh.aspx). So what you get with `offset label` is the offset of `label`, which is an immediate value. So you're looking at two different things: getting the value stored at a particular address, versus getting the address itself.

I don't know what the GAS syntax would be to get the `moffs64` variant, but with NASM you could write `mov rax,[qword label]` (note that this encoding would be longer than if you had simply written `mov rax,[label]` - i.e. `mov r64, r/m64`).

Comment: GAS syntax would be simply `movabs label, %rax`. This assembles to opcode  `48 a1`, which is the only `mov` instruction supporting `moffs64`.